# Django Money - Add two MoneyFields in different currencies and generate output in given currency

Tags: python, django

Hi I've been scratching my head over past few days to figure out how to manipulate dj-money fields.
Here are my two model fields:

```
 client_cost = MoneyField(
    _('client cost'),
    max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2,
    default_currency='AUD',
    null=True,
)

camera_operator_cost = MoneyField(
    _('camera operator cost'),
    max_digits=10,
    decimal_places=2,
    default_currency='AUD',
    null=True,
)
```

They can have completely different currencies (default being 'AUD').

I need to be able to:

- extract currency from these fields. (Need the exact statement).
- add these two fields which could have amounts in any currency.
- reformat the total in whatever currency I want. Let's say total in AU$ is 250 and now i want the same value in US$ which will be ~184US$

Please help.

PS: I'm using this: https://github.com/django-money/django-money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the `Money` instances of `some_instance` with:

```
money1 = some_instance.client_cost
money2 = some_instance.camera_operator_cost
```

So we can perform an attribute fetch.

If you install the [*Exchange rate support*](https://github.com/django-money/django-money#working-with-exchange-rates), you can then exchange these to a currency, and add these together. For example if the given currency is USD, then we can obtain the sum of the two costs in USD with:

```
convert_money(money1, 'USD') + convert_money(money2, 'USD')
```

**EDIT**

For a `Money` object, you can obtain the *amount* and *currency* with `some_money.amount` (a `Decimal` object) and `some_money.currency` (a `Currency` object) respectively.

A `Currency` object attributes like `.code`, `.countries`, `.name`, etc.

If you thus, for example, want to obtain the currency code of `money1`, you can use:

```
money1.currency.code  # will be 'USD', 'EUR', 'AUD', etc.
```

Comment: How will i know the currency of these fields?
Something like:
print(client_cost.currency) // 'USD'

Comment: Hey @Willem Van Onsem, Yes it helped solve my problem. Although the actual solution is slightly different. 
It seems we can directly compare money1.currency with money2.currency. Surprisingly, money1.currency.code gave me an error saying that the .code property doesn't exist. I tried debugging but couldn't understand the issue.

for now, simply doing x.currency == y.currency worked.

For my 3rd point, I must implement an exchange api which is paid and a bit of a headache honestly. So, I gave up on that requirement.